# How to avoid memory leak here?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, singleton, android-context

I'm creating a module (a group of classes to perform functionality) where I need the context object to perform some operations like secure setting read and others.

I do not like to create multiple objects for my classes which ideally is not needed in my case even so i'm doing something like this,

```
class MyModuleFactory {

    private static final String TAG = MyModuleFactory.class.getSimpleName();
    public Context mContext;
    private static HashMap<Context, MyModuleFactory> myInstance = new HashMap<>();

    private MyModuleFactory(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public static synchronized MyModuleFactory getInstance(Context mContext) {
        if(mContext == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Context cannot be null");
            return null;
        }
        if(myInstance.get(mContext.getApplicationContext()) != null) {
            return myInstance.get(mContext.getApplicationContext());
        } else {
            MyModuleFactory myModuleFactory = new MyModuleFactory(mContext);
            myInstance.put(mContext.getApplicationContext(), myModuleFactory);
        }
    }
}
```

My worry here is since I'm holding the context of application here I'm afraid that I could cause memory leak - the reason is because Android can clear up application object and recreate it at anytime. So holding the context behind the application's lifecycle and not allowing to clear the context here could cause memory leak.

What is the better way to force singleton for my module here and also avoiding memory leak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There won't be any memory leak if you are holding a reference to Application context. Application context lives as long as the app is running. It gets destroyed when the app is killed. In that case, even your singleton will be destroyed, so no memory leak will happen.

Just make sure you are holding reference only to the Application context in the singleton, not Activity context.

Check [this post](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-context-in-android-application-330913e32514) for detailed information:

> If you have to create a singleton object for your application and that
>   object needs a context, always pass the application context.
>
> If you pass the activity context here, it will lead to the memory leak
>   as it will keep the reference to the activity and activity will not be
>   garbage collected.

Comment: How long will the context of system_server process will live? Will it remain ever till reboot?

Comment: I haven't heard of the system_server process before. Looks like the device starts that process when the device boots up. So it's not tied to your application at all, and might live as long as the device is switched on. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Since it's a different question, I guess you could post that as a new question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Bob. The reason which I got doubted for the memory leak to happen is after reading this article (https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class) where they said that android can clear the application object and recreate it? Even in that case will the context still remain the same? If so, how is this happening?

Comment: If the application object is being killed by the system, it means the system has killed the app itself, maybe the device has run out of memory and the system had to kill the background running apps. Again in that case, since the app itself got killed, your singleton would be removed from memory too. When the user opens the app again from recent apps for instance, system will recreate the application object, there will be a new context, and it will create even the singletons again.  And the system will restart the Activity where the user had left before. So there won't be any memory leak.

Comment: That article is warning you not to depend solely on any global data that is set in the Application class. When the application is destroyed, those global data will be lost. Unles you manually save it in database or onSaveInstanceState and retrieve it when the Application restarts.

Comment: Glad to help. :)